# Suitable data mining technique for this dataset

Tags: attributes, data-mining, classification, rapidminer

I'm working on a data mining project and would like to mine this dataset [Higher Education Enrolments](http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/higher-education-enrolments-from-datagovau) for interesting patterns or knowledge. My problem is figuring out which technique would work best for the dataset.

I'm currently working on the dataset using RapidMiner 5.0 and I removed two columns (E550 - Reference year, E931 - Total Student EFTSL) from the data as they would not be relevant to the analysis. The rest of the attributes are nominal except StudentID (integer) which I have used as my *id*. I'm currently using classification on it (Naive Bayes) but would like to get the opinion of others, hopefully those who have had more experience in this area. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best technique depends on many factors: type/distribution of training and target attribute, domain, value range of attributes, etc. The best technique to use is the result of data analysis and understanding.

In this particular case, you should clarify which is the attribute to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you already know what you are looking for, and know about the quality of the data source, you should always start by trying various exploratory analysis:

- look at some of the first and second order statistics of all the
  variables
- generate histograms of each variable, to get an idea of the empirical
  distribution of each
- take a look at pairwise scatter plots of variables that might have
  dependency
- try other visualization that you might think of

These would give you a rough idea about what kind of pattern might be present and might be discoverable given the noise level. Then depending on what kind of pattern you are interested in, you could start trying various unsupervised pattern learning methods such as, PCA/ICA/factor analysis, clustering, or supervised methods, such as regression, classification.